# Vue - Firebase updates but switch doesn't

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuex

This code updates the firebase room to busy, as it should, but if I open another browser window to that same page it's not reactive. So I switch to true in one browser but it doesn't update to true in another, even though the database updates.

This code updates the firebase room to busy, as it should, but if I open another browser window to that same page it's not reactive. So I switch to true in one browser but it doesn't update to true in another, even though the database updates.

```
<template v-for="room in getAllRooms">
...
  <v-list-tile-action>
     <v-switch v-model="room.busy" @change="updateBusyRoom(room)" hide-details></v-switch>
  </v-list-tile-action>
...
</template>

export default {
    name: 'about',
    methods: {
      ...mapActions([
        'updateBusyRoom'
      ])
    },
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters([
        'getUserName',
        'getUser',
        'getUserRooms',
        'getAllRooms'
      ])
    }
}
```

I thought that the  v-model of `room.busy`  along with the computed getter of `getAllRooms` would be enough for it to automatically update. Don't computed properties watch for changes to the store and then update things automatically? How do I bind this switch correctly so that in other browsers the switch is updated when the database changes?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [vuexfire](https://github.com/posva/vuexfire). I was able to bind things correctly without vuex but now that I've implemented the vuex store the same method didn't work.